# Mono WCF InstanceContextMode not working

Tags: .net, linux, wcf, mono, opensuse

I have a service that looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface ILabListener
{
    [OperationContract]
    byte[] GetChallenge();
    ...
```

...

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
class LabListener : ILabListener
{
    private byte[] challenge;

    public LabListener()
    {
        [challenge is initialized to random data from RNG]

        File.AppendAllText(Program.LogPath, String.Format("{1} - Starting LabListener session: {2}, challenge: {3}{0}", 
            Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now, OperationContext.Current.SessionId, Convert.ToBase64String(auth.Challenge.Take(16).ToArray())));
    }        

    public byte[] GetChallenge()
    {
        return challenge;  
    }
    ...
```

...

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);                     
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(LabListener), new Uri(String.Format("net.tcp://{0}:800/LabListener", Environment.MachineName)));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ILabListener), binding, "");
```

...

```
LabListenerClient client = new LabListenerClient();
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(client.GetChallenge()); 
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(client.GetChallenge());
```

When hosting this service in MS .net on Windows, the output of each GetChallenge is the same and the constructor for LabListener is only called once.

If I host this in mono 2.6.7 under OpenSuSE 11.3, a new LabListener is created for each call to GetChallenge, and two different values are returned.

this is the log output on the server on Linux:

> 8/26/2010 8:07:57 PM - Starting LabListener session: urn:uuid:5e41d193-c723-4839-abc0-93103dbd63f1, challenge: hDPwoofYUrEjAJ1Q8cWDYw==
>
> 8/26/2010 8:07:57 PM - Starting
>   LabListener session:
>   urn:uuid:5e41d193-c723-4839-abc0-93103dbd63f1,
>   challenge: 6/3M4EhiKrAMM2j47MCIpQ==

How do I correct the mono behavior?

Comment: You should test against the most recent Mono bits. Lots has been fixed in WCF since 2.6...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to build SVN trunk (or nowadays - GIT latest) and try again.

If doesn't work, write to [mono](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/mono-list)/[mono-devel](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/mono-devel-list) mailing list and see the answer.

Probably it a Mono bug and maintainer will ask you to fill a test or a bug